# React - not redirect logged user

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, react-router-dom

I'm writing an app in react and I have a problem with redirection. I'm saving JWT token and simple user data from NodeJS api in localstore. I have private route which redirect unlogged user to login page but if user is logged and if  manually type /login in the URL, user come back to the login page despite already having logged in.

I don't know exactly how to get around it. I was thinking of doing something similar to Private route 
but I don't know if this practice is good and not to be missed.

```
    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {};
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <GlobalStyle />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/:user_name/boards" component={Boards} />
                        <PrivateRoute
                            exact
                            path="/:user_name/boards/:type"
                            component={Board}
                        />
                        <Route component={Error} />
                    </Switch>
                </ThemeProvider>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;

    class PrivateRoute extends Component {
        static contextType = DataContext;
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {};
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
            if (!token || !user) {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
                this.props.history.push('/login');
            }
        }

        render() {
            const { token } = this.context;
            const { component: RouteComponent, ...rest } = this.props;

            return token ? (
                <Route
                    {...rest}
                    render={(routeProps) => <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />}
                />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);

    class Login extends Component {
        static contextType = DataContext;
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            };
        }


        handleChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            });
        };
        submitForm = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { login } = this.context;
            login(this.state).then((res) => {
                this.props.history.push(`/${res.user.user_name}/boards`);
            });
        };
        render() {
            return (
                <StyledForm onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                    <StyledInput
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        placeholder="Podaj adres e-mail"
                    />
                    <StyledInput
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        placeholder="Wprowadz hasło"
                    />
                    <StyledButton type="submit">Zaloguj</StyledButton>
                </StyledForm>
            );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(Login);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code for example?

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should do another component to wrap the Login route (just like you did with the PrivateRoute component). In that component check if the user's already logged in and if he is simply redirect him to another path.